# Oracle Select Query on Same Table (self join)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

It seems to simple, but not getting desired results

I have a table with there data

```
Team_id, Player_id, Player_name Game_cd
1            100     abc        24
1            1000    xyz        24
1            588     ert        24
1            500     you        24
2            600     ops        24
2            700     dps        24
2            900     lmv        24
2            200     hmv        24
```

I have to write a query to get a result like this

```
Home_team home_plr_id home_player away_team away_plr_id away_player
1            100       abc          2         600         ops
1            1000      xyz          2         900         lmv
```

The query I wrote

```
select f1.Team_id as home_team, 
        f1.player_id as home_plr_id,
        f1.player_Name as home_player,
        f2.Team_id as away_team, 
        f2.player_id as away_plr_id,
        f2.player_Name as home_player

from game f1, game f2
where 
f1.team_id<> f2.team_id and
f1.game_cd = f2.game_cd
```

Comment: What is the relation between players from the two teams?  This is not so obvious to me.

Comment: Please provide more details,, What is the join condition to get the away team. How the away columns got related to home columns..

Comment: Is it clear?  I updated it correctly

Comment: not realy, what is a logic behind your joins? i can't see any

Comment: The team 1 is home team and 2 is away team, I need to split those and get the result as I described.

Comment: so why do you join e.g. player 100 and player 600 and not player 100 and player 900? again  what is a logic behind your joins?

Comment: @hotfix, I am not joining the players, My intention is to display players according to their team.

Comment: ok i rephrase my question, why is Player 100 and Player 600 or 1000 and 900 in your example on the same line? why  not 100 and 900  or 588 and 600?

Comment: @hotfix Actually there no paring with home and away players, My intention is to get all home and away players in single query it will be easy for display purpose

Comment: What @hotfix want to ask is that as per your data and query condition, Player 100 will be matched to all 4 players in team 2. and same is with other players. So do you want to see all 4 players in team 2 matched to player 100 in a single row. if not how the pairing will be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative to @Radagast81's self-join is `pivot`, available in your Oracle version:

```
select home_plr_id, home_plr_name,  away_plr_id, away_plr_name
  from (select game.*, 
               row_number() over (partition by team_id order by player_id) rn 
          from game)
  pivot (max(player_id) plr_id, max(player_name) plr_name 
         for team_id in (1 home, 2 away))
```

**<sup>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cb116/3)</sup>**

Players have to be numbered *somehow* (here by ID), it can be done by name, null or even random. This numbering is needed only to put them in same rows. Pivot works also if numbers of players in teams differs.

Comment: Thank you, It works One question team_id in (1 home, 2 away) can it be s select query

Comment: Nope, `in` clause in `pivot` query requires specific parameters. If you want team numbers as result of other query you should probably use self-join version. There are some ways to make *dynamic* pivot, but they are complicated, I don't recommend them for this task.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear how you want to pair a home player with an away player. But provided that you don't care about that, the following might be what you are looking for:

```
WITH game_p AS (SELECT team_id, player_id, player_name, game_cd
                     , ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY team_id, game_cd ORDER BY player_id) pos
                     , dense_rank() over (PARTITION BY game_cd ORDER BY team_id) team_pos 
                  FROM game) 
SELECT NVL(f1.game_cd, f2.game_cd) AS game_cd
     , f1.Team_id as home_team
     , f1.player_id as home_plr_id
     , f1.player_Name as home_player
     , f2.Team_id as away_team
     , f2.player_id as away_plr_id
     , f2.player_Name as away_player
  FROM (SELECT * FROM game_p WHERE team_pos = 1) f1
  FULL JOIN (SELECT * FROM game_p WHERE team_pos = 2) f2
  ON f1.game_cd = f2.game_cd
  AND f1.pos = f2.pos
```

The new column `POS` gives any player of each team a position to pair them with the other team.
The new column `TEAM_POS` is to get the team_id mapped to the values 1 and 2, as the team_id's can differ per game.

Finally do a `FULL JOIN` to get the final list. If the number of players are allways the same for both teams you can do a normal join instead...

Comment: The intention is to display home and away team in front end. Rather than looping I can get it from single query

Comment: Might be better to loop twice then to do a single query, as you have no correlation between the players of team1 and team2...